# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054

Tags: sql, codeigniter, function

i tried to make option delete for my CI with sql, but why its still error?

**error warning:**

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'sip' in 'where clause'

select * from t_label where label = sip

Filename: E:\web\rbt.new\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

**code:**

```
function hapus($id_user){
            if($this->session->userdata('username')==TRUE) {
                $name = $this->db->query("select USER_NAME from t_user where USER_ID = $id_user")->row();
                $id_label = $this->db->query("select * from t_label where label = $name->USER_NAME")->row();
                $this->db->query("delete from t_label, t_publisher where t_label.id_label = t_publisher.id_label and t_label.id_label = $id_label->id_label");
                $this->db->delete('t_user', array('USER_ID' => $id_user));
                redirect("registrasi/reg");
            }
        }
```

whats wrong with my code? really need help here

Comment: what is the result of $name->USER_NAME

Comment: dear kanishka panamaldeniya, its username that i want to delete from t_user, t_publisher, and t_label

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the string. Try this:

```
$id_label = $this->db->query("select * from t_label where label = '" . $name->USER_NAME . "'")->row();
```

Comment: dear joedixon, thanks before for the answer.
i did try your code, but its still error,

'Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where t_label.id_label = t_publisher.id_label and t_label.id_label = 18' at line 1

delete from t_label, t_publisher where t_label.id_label = t_publisher.id_label and t_label.id_label = 18

Filename: E:\web\rbt.new\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330'

what should i do, then?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It looks like you're trying to delete from 2 tables in one statement. Try splitting it up as follows:

`$this->db->query("delete from t_label where t_label.id_label = t_label.id_label = $id_label->id_label");
$this->db->query("delete from t_publisher where t_publisher.id_label = t_label.id_label = $id_label->id_label");`

Comment: dear joedixon, err, would u like to help me again? now i have some problem in update option.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337968/database-error-occurred-error-number-1062/13337994#comment18211207_13337994 thanks before :)