# Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1062

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sql-update

i tried to make option update three table with one execution for my CI with sql there, but why its still error?

**this is the error warning:**

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry '0' for key 1

UPDATE `t_publisher` SET `id_publisher` = NULL, `publisher` = NULL, `artis` = NULL, `id_label` = NULL WHERE `id_publisher` = '113'
```

**this is the code:**

```
function update($id_user=null)
  {
   if (($this->input->post('submit') == 'Update')){
    $user=$this->input->post('username');
    $pass=$this->input->post('userpassword');
    $ussta=$this->input->post('userstatus');
    $usty=$this->input->post('usertype');

   $data = array(
    'user_name' => $user,
    'user_pass' => $pass,
    'user_status' => $ussta,
    'user_type' => $usty);

    $this->db->where('user_id', $this->input->post('id'), $data);
    $this->db->update("t_user",$data);

   $data1 = array(
    'id_publisher' => $id_publis,
    'publisher' => $publis,
    'artis' => $ar,
    'id_label' => $id_lab);

    $this->db->where('id_publisher', $this->input->post('id'), $data);
    $this->db->update("t_publisher",$data1);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    die();

   $data2 = array(
    'id_label' => $id_lab,
    'label' => $label);

    $this->db->where('id_label', $this->input->post('id'), $data);
    $this->db->update("t_label",$data2);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    die();
    redirect("registrasi/reg");
   }
    $var['data'] = $this->db->query("select * from t_user where USER_ID= '$id_user'")->row_array();  
    $var1['data'] = $this->db->query("select * from t_publisher where id_publisher = '$id_publis'")->row_array();
    $var2['data'] = $this->db->query("select * from t_label where id_label = '$id_lab'")->row_array();
    $this->load->view('update', $var,$var1,$var2);
}
```

whats wrong with my code? please help. thanks before.

Comment: You should post the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: have you set your primary key as auto increment

Comment: dear Chris Henry, create table for what? || 
dear raheel shan, yea i set it as auto increment

Answer (score 2):

Your `UPDATE` clause is setting the `id_publisher` column to `NULL`, and, based on the name of the column and the error you're receiving, *that* column is the table's `PRIMARY KEY` with a setting of `unsigned NOT NULL`.

Because of this, when you do `id_publisher = NULL`, MySQL converts it to `id_publisher = 0` due to the `unsigned` part. This will execute fine the first time, however, when you run it on a second row you will now be attempting to insert a *second* primary-key value of `0`, which is not allowed.

Based on the location of the `die()` statement in your sample code, I'm assuming the following block is the culprit:

```
   $data1 = array(
    'id_publisher' => $id_publis,
    'publisher' => $publis,
    'artis' => $ar,
    'id_label' => $id_lab);

    $this->db->where('id_publisher', $this->input->post('id'), $data);
    $this->db->update("t_publisher",$data1);
```

Here, your `$id_publis` variable is either empty or null.

I would suggest to either remove the `id_publisher = NULL` portion from the `UPDATE` clause which is as simple as removing `'id_publisher' => $id_publis,` from the `$data1` array, or rethink the reason you actually need to set it to `null` to begin with (in this case, would deleting the row be more beneficial?)

Comment: dear newfurniturey, so, i just need to delete 'id_publisher' => $id_publis ? because when im clicking PK option, it didnt change. but, if i delete the 'id_publisher' => $id_publis, it contain error UPDATE `t_publisher` SET `publisher` = NULL, `artis` = NULL, `id_label` = NULL WHERE `id_publisher` = 0

Comment: @user1781895 What is the actual error in the new query? It looks like you're `WHERE` clause is `id_publisher = 0`, which means you're editing one of the erroneous rows from earlier, however, I'm not sure what your exact error is in this case just by reading the query.

Comment: UPDATE `t_publisher` SET `publisher` = NULL, `artis` = NULL, `id_label` = NULL WHERE `id_publisher` = '19' || but field username in t_user is changing

Comment: @user1781895 That's not really an error though. The lines above the ones I've mentioned in my answer have `$this->db->update("t_user",$data);`. This updates your `t_user` table...

Comment: yea.. its work in the database, but only in t_user.. how about t_publisher and t_label?

Comment: @user1781895 You're using `$this->input->post('id')` for the `id` for each of the three tables. Though possible, I highly doubt that the same `id` is used for `t_user`, `t_publisher`, and `t_label`. Do you have separate fields for each and this is an accident, or what is the logic behind this?

Comment: dear newfurniturey, ah, yea.. it has different id name.. i did change the code a little.. here's the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356572/updating-three-table-with-one-execution