# updating three table with one execution

Tags: sql, codeigniter, sql-update

i try to updating three tables with one button execution, but why just t_user that changed? t_publisher and t_label didnt change and no error warning..

```
function update($id_user=null){

        if (($this->input->post('submit') == 'Update')){
            $user=$this->input->post('username');
            $pass=$this->input->post('userpassword');
            $ussta=$this->input->post('userstatus');
            $usty=$this->input->post('usertype');
            $id_label = $this->db->query("select ID_LABEL from t_label where LABEL = '$name->USER_NAME'")->row();
            $id_publisher = $this->db->query("select ID_PUBLISHER from t_publisher where PUBLISHER = '$name->USER_NAME'")->row();

        $data = array(
            'USER_NAME' => $user,
            'USER_PASS' => $pass,
            'USER_STATUS' => $ussta,
            'USER_TYPE' => $usty
            );

        $data2 = array(
            'LABEL' => $user,
            );

        $data3 = array(
            'PUBLISHER' => $user,
            );

        $this->db->where('USER_ID', $this->input->post('id'));
        $this->db->update('t_user', $data);
        $this->db->where('ID_LABEL', $this->input->post('$id_label'));
        $this->db->update('t_label', $data2);
        $this->db->where('ID_PUBLISHER', $this->input->post('$id_publisher'));
        $this->db->update('t_publisher', $data3);
        redirect("registrasi/reg");
        }
        $var['data'] = $this->db->query("select * from t_user where USER_ID= '$id_user'")->row_array();  
        $this->load->view('update', $var);
        }
```

please help :)

Comment: where is ID_LABEL in your first query coming from?

Comment: and why dont you check it step by step with echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: id_label on t_label.. my friend did it yesterday..

Comment: make sure your select queries are running with echo $this->db->last_query()

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function update( $id_user = NULL ){
    if ( ( $this->input->post( 'submit' ) === 'Update' ) ) {
        $user = $this->input->post( 'username' );
        $pass = $this->input->post( 'userpassword' );
        $ussta = $this->input->post( 'userstatus' );
        $usty = $this->input->post( 'usertype' );

        $sql = "SELECT ID_LABEL FROM t_label WHERE LABEL = ?";
        $id_label = $this->db->query( $sql, array( $name->USER_NAME ) )->row();

        $sql = "SELECT ID_PUBLISHER FROM t_publisher WHERE PUBLISHER = ?";
        $id_publisher = $this->db->query( $sql, array( $name->USER_NAME ) )->row();

        $data = array(
            'USER_NAME' => $user,
            'USER_PASS' => $pass,
            'USER_STATUS' => $ussta,
            'USER_TYPE' => $usty
            );

        $data2 = array(
            'LABEL' => $user,
            );

        $data3 = array(
            'PUBLISHER' => $user,
            );

        $this->db->where('USER_ID', $this->input->post('id'));
        $this->db->update('t_user', $data);

        $this->db->where('ID_LABEL', $id_label);
        $this->db->update('t_label', $data2);

        $this->db->where('ID_PUBLISHER', $id_publisher);
        $this->db->update('t_publisher', $data3);

        redirect("registrasi/reg");
    }

    $var['data'] = $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE USER_ID= '$id_user'")->row_array();
    $this->load->view('update', $var);
}
```

I'm a bit confused. Is it a model file? If it's so, why there is a `redirect` command? And also why there is a `$this->load->view()`? And once more, where $name came from? You assign `$id_user` as default parameter, where do you use it in this file?

Comment: dear AMYunus, this isnt model. i'll put it in the controller. because it must back to current page. because view page and coding (controller) page is different so i must load the view page. $name is for take USER_NAME. $id_user used to updating the t_user, if i didnt place it there, the t_user wont change.

Comment: Oh, so you code database thing in controller. Okay. Anyway, have you tried code above? or you have found your self answer?