# SQL Database Error Occurred : Error Number: 1062

Tags: php, mysql

I got an error while I try to insert a data to the phpmyadmin database

the **email** column is not a primary key or unique key in the **answer** table. but it is the primary key of another table.

Why this occurred?

```
 A Database Error Occurred

 Error Number: 1062
 Duplicate entry 'work@gmail.com' for key 'email'
 INSERT INTO `answer` (`ansbody`, `ansaccept`, `ansrep`, `ansqid`, `ansemail`) VALUES ('aaa',                     'false', 0, '15', 'work@gmail.com')

 Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\StackTrace\system\database\DB_driver.php
 Line Number: 330
```

Comment: it's not a "phpmyadmin" database. phpmyadmin is a tool to work with a mysql database.

Comment: It isn't a unique key? The error message says otherwise :-?

Comment: Please run `show index from answer` and add the output to your question.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Sir I figure out by using your instruction.
show index from answer and its show many keys but not the primary key in the many attributes in the table. So I drop the able and recreates. Then its works fin.
Thank you

Comment: So: 1) Your table doesn't have primary key (a bad practice) 2) You possibly had a unique index on `email` (just like the error message said) but we'll never know for sure.

Comment: I user an other attribute as primary key but not for email address and also i dont want to have a unique email address.

Answer (score 0):

you made your email as primary key and maybe there is already a record present by this email in database table.

Comment: You just think?!?!? you should be damn sure, there is error with "Duplicate entry.."

Comment: @VipulHadiya you can't be damn sure unless you have seen the structure person who asked the question might have set other column as primary key so you can only guess.

Comment: Have you looked at this : Duplicate entry 'work@gmail.com' for key 'email' in his question?

Comment: 'email' is not the primary key in this table(Answer)
but it is primary key of another table(user)

Comment: table user is not a issue you are adding value in table(answer) can you share table(answer) structure with me?

Answer (score 0):

You may trying to insert into unique column `email` which has already having the value `work@gmail.com` If this is not the case this may help you [Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1062](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337968/database-error-occurred-error-number-1062)