# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054

Tags: codeigniter

A Database Error Occurred  `Error Number: 1054`

```
Unknown column ' Fecha_Salida BETWEEN 2013-06-05 AND 2013-06-05' in 'where clause'  SELECT `Fecha_Entrada`, `Fecha_Salida` FROM (`tbl_fecha`) WHERE ` Fecha_Salida BETWEEN 2013-06-05 AND 2013-06-05
```

This is the code that giving me this error.

```
$this->db->select('Fecha_Entrada,Fecha_Salida')->from('tbl_fecha')->where(" Fecha_Salida BETWEEN $fee AND $fes");
$query = $this->db->get();
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    echo $row->Fecha_Entrada;
}
```

Comment: That means table 'tbl_fecha' does not have a column with name 'Fecha_Salida'.Can you show the select query you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267243/a-database-error-occurred-error-number-1054)

Answer (score 0):

May be there is no column named Fecha_Salida in your table and consider the cases of the name also and try to use where_between like this

```
$this->db->select('Fecha_Entrada,Fecha_Salida')->from('tbl_fecha')->where_between(" Fecha_Salida , $fee , $fes");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **select()** function in pass **array argument**..like

```
 $this->db->select(array('Fecha_Entrada','Fecha_Salida'))->from('tbl_fecha')->where(" Fecha_Salida BETWEEN $fee AND $fes");
```

Try it...

this code is 100% working, if **Fecha_Salida** field is **exist in database table**.. so may be help you this code