# A Database Error Occurred Error Number -1054

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

A Database Error Occurred `Error Number: 1054`

This was the error which i got:

```
Unknown column 'users.id' in 'field list'

SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`username` FROM (`users`) JOIN `user_autologin` ON `user_autologin`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `user_autologin`.`user_id` = '36' AND `user_autologin`.`key_id` = 'bb625653fd63c5b3460895e31e51939b'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\2010105\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

But as I'm a newbie on handling `database`, i just cant figure out where it's going wrong.

This is my `MySQL` file: [file](http://pastebin.com/bp2G3hiU)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267243/a-database-error-occurred-error-number-1054)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary key in users table isnt **id** but **userid**

So right call is:

```
SELECT `users`.`userid`,
       `users`.`username`
FROM (`users`)
JOIN `user_autologin` ON `user_autologin`.`user_id` = `users`.`userid`
WHERE `user_autologin`.`user_id` = '36'
  AND `user_autologin`.`key_id` = 'bb625653fd63c5b3460895e31e51939b
```

Comment: Thanks.Where should i change this `SELECT` statement? behind my code?

Answer (score 1):

Use alias names like this:

```
SELECT USR.`userid`, USR.`username`
FROM `users` U
JOIN `user_autologin` UAL ON UAL.`user_id` = USR.`userid`
WHERE UAL.`user_id` = '36'
AND UAL.`key_id` = 'bb625653fd63c5b3460895e31e51939b'
```